# What is the point of R3 in this reference design?

Tags: digital-logic, resistors, pullup, pulldown

[image]

The [TPS565201 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps565201.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1603950399032&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.jp%252F) (page 5) specifies that EN has a typical resistance of 245k to GND so I know it is safe to connect EN directly to 12V (max 19V rated).

My questions is if there is already an internal 245k pulldown to GND on EN, what is the point of the 10k R3 resistor?

Is it a cue for designers to add an external switch or is there some internal thing I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps the designer had a long HMI wire for this and wanted to add ESD current limiting.

Comment: @jsotola - R2 is part of the feedback voltage divider that sets the output voltage, most engineers would not call it a "pulldown resistor".

Comment: It is not at all obvious from the datasheet what the resistor on the EN pin is for.

Comment: When referencing a datasheet please include a link so we don't have to go looking for it. As you've mentioned it's not obvious why R3 is specified given they have characterised the internal resistance to ground.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a safety current limiter in case EN (inadvertently) pulled above the max allowed input or pulled negative.

Comment: You could try asking TI. Sometimes they answer these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a switching power supply chip with large ground currents thorough the synchronous rectifier.

It’s unsafe to connect the pin directly to ground if the chip ground is higher than +300mV (see absolute maximum ratings).